# How to get the value of this.id in string?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a character d with the value of this.id given by below code as like :  dclicki25 . How I can get this?

```
$('.divclasss').click(function(){

console.log(this.id); //clicki25 , clicki26 based on the clicking element

});
```

Comment: `console.log('d' + this.id);`

Comment: @Satpal   from console.log into a variable or string.

Comment: `var a = 'd' + this.id;`

Comment: yeah I was getting error undefined because of some other problem , I also know the concatenation , I was fool!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

just Concatenatewith **d** like this

```
$('.divclasss').click(function(){

console.log('d'+ this.id); //clicki25 , clicki26 based on the clicking element

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate this.id with the string 'd' very easily with the below small change:

```
$('.divclasss').click(function(){
    console.log('d'+ this.id); //clicki25 , clicki26 based on the clicking element
});
```